# filter date index in xts format

Tags: r, quantmod

I download some rates from FRED, how I can filter the index date in order to keep only the dates after '2010' ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show the `dput` of example

Comment: My question is general. I am just wondering if there is a way to filter an index column in R.

Comment: Depends on the structure of the data

Comment: Maybe `yourobj[year(index(yourobj)) >= 2010]`

Comment: For example in this case is an 'xts' 'zoo' .

Comment: then the above code should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it is an `xts` object, then we extract the `year` from index to create a logical vector for subsetting

```
library(xts)
xt1[lubridate::year(index(xt1)) >= 2010]
```

---

Or use `subset` with `%>%`

```
library(dplyr)
xt1 %>%
       subset(year(index(.))>= 2010)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
xt1 <- xts(rnorm(50), order.by = seq(as.Date('2009-01-01'), 
    length.out = 50, by = '1 month'))
```

Comment: Is there any way to pipe this line?

Answer (score 7):

xts accepts / notation as shown below:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("DGS3MO", src = "FRED") # generate test data

DGS3MO["2010/"]
##            DGS3MO
## 2010-01-01     NA
## 2010-01-04   0.08
## 2010-01-05   0.07
## 2010-01-06   0.06
## 2010-01-07   0.05
## 2010-01-08   0.05
## ...snip...
```

Alternately, xts has a window method:

```
window(DGS3MO, start = "2010-01-01")
##            DGS3MO
## 2010-01-01     NA
## 2010-01-04   0.08
## 2010-01-05   0.07
## 2010-01-06   0.06
## 2010-01-07   0.05
## 2010-01-08   0.05
## ...snip...
```